# Accessing Firefox chrome style from user script

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I'm looking for a way to write a user script for Firefox that triggers changes in the way the browser itself looks. I know how to write user styles and user scripts but I couldn't figure a way to bring them together without having to write my own add-on. Does greasemonkey offer this capability?

Comment: No, Greasemonkey cannot alter the browser styles/chrome.  I believe *Stylish* can still do this but haven't tried in a long while.

Comment: Yes, Stylish can change the styles, but in a static way, I believe.

Comment: Well, if you want to dynamically do it, your only choice is to make an Add-on (extension).